# Jquery quicksearch the search results don't match

Tags: jquery, asp.net, search, gridview

I'm implementing searches within a gridview using the "quicksearch" library which it's awesome.

I've used this library before and I never had any problems prior to this, when ever I try to use it I can't seem to make it work

I really hope someone can point me on what I might be doing wrong.

Here's the code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/jquery.js" language="javascript"> </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/quicksearch.js"   language="javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

 $(function () {
        $('.search_textbox').each(function (i) {
            $(this).quicksearch("[id*=<%=dgridTest.ClientID%>] tr:not(:has(th))", {
                'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {
                    return $(row).children(":eq(" + i + ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0].toLowerCase()) != -1;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

My HTML page:

```
 <asp:GridView 
            ID="dgridTest" 
            runat="server"  
            UseAccessibleHeader="true"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames = "Name" 
            PageSize="15" 
            OnRowCommand="dgridEmpleados_RowCommand" 
            Font-Size="Small" 
            BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" 
            BorderColor="Tan" 
            BorderWidth="1px" 
            CellPadding="2" 
            ForeColor="Black" 
            GridLines="None"  >

           <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" 
      HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="True"> 
        <FooterTemplate> 
      <asp:Label 
       ID="lblNuemeroPer" 
        runat="server" 
          Text="">
                        </asp:Label> 
         </FooterTemplate> 
           <ItemTemplate> 
   <asp:Label 
         ID="lblNumPer" 
        runat="server" 
          CssClass="label label-success" 
          Font-Size="Small" 
          Text ='<%#Bind("Name") %>'>
                 </asp:Label> 
</ItemTemplate>                              
  <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
        <HeaderTemplate >
    <asp:Label 
     ID="lblsearch " 
      runat="server" 
      Text="No. Permiso">
      </asp:Label>
      <input id="txtSearch " 
          type="text" 
       class="search_textbox" 
       maxlength="30"
          style="color:#777777; 
      width:150px; 
      background-image:url(../../Images/Search.png); background-position:right; 
   background-repeat:no-repeat;"   />
```

Here is my search box field:
[image: first image]

And when ever I try to search for something, nothing comes up.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
     $(function ()

     {   

    $('.search_textbox').each(function (i) {

    $(this).quicksearch("[id*=dgridTest] tr:not(:has(th))", {

            'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {

    return $(row).children(":eq(" + i + 

    ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0].toLowerCase()) != -1;

 }

        });


    });

});
```

try this.....